# Position 2 items per row in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

this is my html structure.

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='title'> Some title </div>
  <div class='element'> Element 1</div>
  <div class='element'> Element 2</div>
  <div class='element'> Element 3</div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the parent is

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

In the desktop view, the elements look like this:

```
Some Title   Element1   Element2  Element 3
```

When the window is smaller, the elements wrap like this:

```
Some Title   Element1   Element2  
Element 3
```

Is there a way to put two elements per row when the wrap property starts to take effect? Like this:

```
Some Title   Element1 
Element2     Element 3
```

Comment: Is flexbox mandatory ? You could try with 'display: grid' instead

Comment: You may need to nest a pair of inner rows as flex items. Can your markup be modified?

Comment: yes, my markup can be modified as needed.

Comment: Not without media queries, no.

Comment: there are multiple ways of achieving this, what trouble did you have with this?

Comment: I've tried with media queries, but in the project I'm working on, there are specific media queries I have to use and cannot change them, the elements start wrapping before the media query hits, so I wanted to know if there's a way of achieving it without them.

Answer (score 2):

Flex-basis sets the initial main size of a flex item. It sets the size of the content box unless otherwise set with box-sizing. You can learn more from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).

Thanks to @Bart Hofland.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.parent > div {
   flex-basis: 25%;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .parent > div {
     flex-basis: 50%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='title'> Some title </div>
  <div class='element'> Element 1</div>
  <div class='element'> Element 2</div>
  <div class='element'> Element 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks better. :) However, it still tends to wrap to three columns first when the elements' contents are somewhat longer. I myself tried to disable wrapping, define an initial `flex-basis: 25%;` for the child `div`s and switch to `flex-basis: 50%` for smaller screens using that `@media` rule. But I cannot get it to work. If I do that, it always stays in a 4-column layout even on smaller screens. Perhaps it's not intended to work that way or I am making some silly mistake.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is expected behavior, anyway, updated again. What do you think, guys?

Comment: I looked at this issue again this morning. It seems that using `nowrap` causes the issue here. Changing it back to `wrap` did the trick for me.